# What does 'tip an election' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Among a hundred voters, only a few whose initial preferences were uncertain will vote differently about a school issue if their precinct is located in a school rather that in a church - but a few percent **could tip an election**.

If additional context is needed:

1. [Sentence itself](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=oV1tXT3HigoC&pg=PT54&lpg=PT54&dq=%22but%20a%20few%20percent%20could%20tip%20an%20election%22&source=bl&ots=bZPvLJ1xmV&sig=ACfU3U1rYJHA4kf1a-qTdDe0PG8nVRgQYg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizvcOpv7DnAhXlpYsKHcTADlYQ6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22but%20a%20few%20percent%20could%20tip%20an%20election%22&f=false).
2. [Preceding info](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ZuKTvERuPG8C&pg=PA55&dq=%22our%20vote%20should%20not%20be%20affected%20by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyh6OrwLDnAhXq-SoKHSssBVIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22our%20vote%20should%20not%20be%20affected%20by%22&f=false).

Comment: *Tip something* - "to turn the trend of favor, control, etc" . For instance, `Martians wanted to tip the election in favor of Mr. Smith.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to **tip the balance​/​scales** (please read more [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tip-the-balance-scales)):

> to give someone or something enough of an advantage to influence a result or decision

You could translate **tip the election** as:

> to give someone or something enough of an advantage to influence a result of the election.

For example, *Martians wanted to **tip the election** in favor of Mr. Smith*.

### Update

As noted by @Lambie, **tip the election** can be also translated as **tip the balance or scales of the election**.

Comment: tip the election is short for tip the balance or scales of the election. But you genera idea is fine.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your feedback! I've added your remark to the answer.